# Apache Camel simple variable expansion from a property

Tags: apache-camel, properties-file

Is it possible to expand a simple expression contained in a property value?

I would like to dynamically create a filename from a property string.
In my .properties file I have.

```
 part.a=SFAC
    part.b=SSPCW
    part.c=TXT
    file.name={{part.a}}.{{part.b}}.${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.{{part.c}}
```

my route I have

`.setHeader("CamelFileName").simple("properties:file.name")`

What I get for a file name is SFAC.SSPCW.${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.TXT
What I want is SFAC.SSPCW.20230501.TXT

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily in camel its basic example .You can see Hello world in console when run it this snippet

```
 from("timer:weather")
                    .setProperty("goHere",constant("lma"))
                    .toD("direct:${exchangeProperty.goHere}");
    
            from("direct:lma")
                    .log("Hello world");
```